# Crystal lang - overriding "to string" method

Tags: crystal-lang

How to override the "to string" method of an object?

I'm getting the following when printing my object to console:

```
#<User:0x7fdd9811eb80>
```

I'm required to have a user-readable version of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the [`#to_s`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.6.2/Object.html#to_s%28io%3AIO%29%3ANil-instance-method) method. For me it was the following within the class definition:

```
def to_s() : String
    first_name + " " + last_name
end
```

Comment: It's more efficient to override `to_s(IO)` instead.